# Query to represent percentages in terms of min and max

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a column that contain some values:

```
Values
 10
 20
 30
 40
 50
```

I need a query that would basically give me two columns like this :

```
Values  PercentageValues
10        0
20        x
30        y
40        z
50       100
```

The way the values are calculated is this : 10(`min`) is considered 0 % and 50(`max`) is considered is considered to be 100%. So x which is a difference of 10  from `min` will be:

```
x= 100/(50-10) * 10 = 25
```

P.S: Ideally I would like to have a query that can run in both Oracle and SQL Server.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using window functions:

```
select t.value,
       (value - minvalue) * 100.0/(maxvalue - minvalue) 
from (select t.*,
             min(value) over () as minvalue,
             max(value) over () as maxvalue
      from t
     ) t
```

You can do the same thing with an explicit join:

```
select t.value,
       (value - minvalue) * 100.0/(maxvalue - minvalue) 
from t cross join
     (select min(value) as minvalue, max(value) as maxvalue
      from t
     ) const
```

Comment: @Inquisitive, it is the table alias given to the inline view.

Answer (score -1):

```
select  100.0 / (maxval - minval) * ([Values] - minval)
from    (
        select  *
        ,       min([Values]) over () as minval
        ,       max([Values]) over () as maxval
        from    Table1
        ) SubQuerALias
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f9321/7/0)

Comment: @joeframbach: This works for all numbers between 10 and 50.  The OP has not defined behavior for values outside that range.

Comment: I think it's fairly obvious what the behavior outside that range is.

Comment: OP asked for something that worked in both SQL Server and Oracle. `[]` arround an identifier does not work on Oracle, where one would need to change their identifer to something that doesn't class with a keyword. (Actually double quotes work, but it turns the identifier into a case sensitive one which is ugly and unrecommended.)